# ipython with MPI clustering using machinefile

Tags: ipython, cluster-computing, mpich, ipython-parallel, mpi4py

I have successfully configured mpi with mpi4py support across three nodes, as per testing of the hellowworld.py script in the mpi4py demo directory:

`gms@host:~/development/mpi$ mpiexec -f machinefile -n 10 python ~/development/mpi4py/demo/helloworld.py`

```
Hello, World! I am process 3 of 10 on host.
Hello, World! I am process 1 of 10 on worker1.
Hello, World! I am process 6 of 10 on host.
Hello, World! I am process 2 of 10 on worker2.
Hello, World! I am process 4 of 10 on worker1.
Hello, World! I am process 9 of 10 on host.
Hello, World! I am process 5 of 10 on worker2.
Hello, World! I am process 7 of 10 on worker1.
Hello, World! I am process 8 of 10 on worker2.
Hello, World! I am process 0 of 10 on host.
```

I am now trying to get this working in ipython and have added my machinefile to my $IPYTHON_DIR/profile_mpi/ipcluster_config.py file, as follows:

```
c.MPILauncher.mpi_args = ["-machinefile", "/home/gms/development/mpi/machinefile"]
```

I then start iPython notebook on my head node using the command: `ipython notebook --profile=mpi --ip=* --port=9999 --no-browser &`

and, voila, I can access it just fine from another device on my local network. However, when I run helloworld.py from iPython notebook, I only get a response from the head node: `Hello, World! I am process 0 of 10 on host.`

I started mpi from iPython with 10 engines, but...

I further configured these parameters, just in case

in $IPYTHON_DIR/profile_mpi/ipcluster_config.py

```
c.IPClusterEngines.engine_launcher_class = 'MPIEngineSetLauncher'
```

in $IPYTHON_DIR/profile_mpi/ipengine_config.py

```
c.MPI.use = 'mpi4py'
```

in $IPYTHON_DIR/profile_mpi/ipcontroller_config.py

```
c.HubFactory.ip = '*'
```

However, these did not help, either.

What am I missing to get this working correctly?

**EDIT UPDATE 1**

I now have NFS mounted directories on my worker nodes, and thus, am fulfilling the requirement "Currently ipcluster requires that the IPYTHONDIR/profile_/security directory live on a shared filesystem that is seen by both the controller and engines." to be able to use `ipcluster` to start my controller and engines, using the command `ipcluster start --profile=mpi -n 6 &`.

So, I issue this on my head node, and then get:

`2016-03-04 20:31:26.280 [IPClusterStart] Starting ipcluster with [daemon=False]
2016-03-04 20:31:26.283 [IPClusterStart] Creating pid file: /home/gms/.config/ipython/profile_mpi/pid/ipcluster.pid
2016-03-04 20:31:26.284 [IPClusterStart] Starting Controller with LocalControllerLauncher
2016-03-04 20:31:27.282 [IPClusterStart] Starting 6 Engines with MPIEngineSetLauncher
2016-03-04 20:31:57.301 [IPClusterStart] Engines appear to have started successfully`

Then, proceed to issue the same command to start the engines on the other nodes, but I get:

`2016-03-04 20:31:33.092 [IPClusterStart] Removing pid file: /home/gms/.config/ipython/profile_mpi/pid/ipcluster.pid
2016-03-04 20:31:33.095 [IPClusterStart] Starting ipcluster with [daemon=False]
2016-03-04 20:31:33.100 [IPClusterStart] Creating pid file: /home/gms/.config/ipython/profile_mpi/pid/ipcluster.pid
2016-03-04 20:31:33.111 [IPClusterStart] Starting Controller with LocalControllerLauncher
2016-03-04 20:31:34.098 [IPClusterStart] Starting 6 Engines with MPIEngineSetLauncher
[1]+  Stopped                 ipcluster start --profile=mpi -n 6`

with no confirmation that the `Engines appear to have started successfully` ...

Even more confusing, when I do a `ps au` on the worker nodes, I get:

```
gms       3862  0.1  2.5  38684 23740 pts/0    T    20:31   0:01 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/ipcluster start --profile=mpi -n 6
gms       3874  0.1  1.7  21428 16772 pts/0    T    20:31   0:01 /usr/bin/python -c from IPython.parallel.apps.ipcontrollerapp import launch_new_instance; launch_new_instance() --profile-dir /home/gms/.co
gms       3875  0.0  0.2   4768  2288 pts/0    T    20:31   0:00 mpiexec -n 6 -machinefile /home/gms/development/mpi/machinefile /usr/bin/python -c from IPython.parallel.apps.ipengineapp import launch_new
gms       3876  0.0  0.4   5732  4132 pts/0    T    20:31   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh -x 192.168.1.1 "/usr/bin/hydra_pmi_proxy" --control-port 192.168.1.200:36753 --rmk user --launcher ssh --demux poll --pgid 0 -
gms       3877  0.0  0.1   4816  1204 pts/0    T    20:31   0:00 /usr/bin/hydra_pmi_proxy --control-port 192.168.1.200:36753 --rmk user --launcher ssh --demux poll --pgid 0 --retries 10 --proxy-id 1
gms       3878  0.0  0.4   5732  4028 pts/0    T    20:31   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh -x 192.168.1.201 "/usr/bin/hydra_pmi_proxy" --control-port 192.168.1.200:36753 --rmk user --launcher ssh --demux poll --pgid 0
gms       3879  0.0  0.6   8944  6008 pts/0    T    20:31   0:00 /usr/bin/python -c from IPython.parallel.apps.ipengineapp import launch_new_instance; launch_new_instance() --profile-dir /home/gms/.config
gms       3880  0.0  0.6   8944  6108 pts/0    T    20:31   0:00 /usr/bin/python -c from IPython.parallel.apps.ipengineapp import launch_new_instance; launch_new_instance() --profile-dir /home/gms/.config
```

Where the ip addresses in processes 3376 and 3378 are from the other hosts in the cluster. But...

When I run a similar test directly using ipython, all I get is a response from the localhost (even though, minus, ipython, this works directly with mpi and mpi4py as noted in my original post):

```
gms@head:~/development/mpi$ ipython test.py
head[3834]: 0/1

gms@head:~/development/mpi$ mpiexec -f machinefile -n 10 ipython test.py
worker1[3961]: 4/10
worker1[3962]: 7/10
head[3946]: 6/10
head[3944]: 0/10
worker2[4054]: 5/10
worker2[4055]: 8/10
head[3947]: 9/10
worker1[3960]: 1/10
worker2[4053]: 2/10
head[3945]: 3/10
```

I still seem to be missing something obvious, although I am convinced my configuration is now correct. One thing that pops out, is when I start `ipcluster` on my worker nodes, I get this: `2016-03-04 20:31:33.092 [IPClusterStart] Removing pid file: /home/gms/.config/ipython/profile_mpi/pid/ipcluster.pid`

**EDIT UPDATE 2**

This is more to document what is happening and, hopefully, ultimately what gets this working:

I cleaned out my log files and reissued `ipcluster start --profile=mpi -n 6 &`

And now see 6-log files for my engines, and 1 for my controller:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 gms gms 12288 Mar  6 03:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 gms gms  4096 Mar  6 03:31 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 gms gms  1313 Mar  6 03:28 ipcontroller-15664.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 gms gms   598 Mar  6 03:28 ipengine-15669.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 gms gms   598 Mar  6 03:28 ipengine-15670.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 gms gms   499 Mar  6 03:28 ipengine-4405.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 gms gms   499 Mar  6 03:28 ipengine-4406.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 gms gms   499 Mar  6 03:28 ipengine-4628.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 gms gms   499 Mar  6 03:28 ipengine-4629.log
```

Looking in the log for ipcontroller it looks like only one engine registered:

```
2016-03-06 03:28:12.469 [IPControllerApp] Hub listening on tcp://*:34540 for registration.
2016-03-06 03:28:12.480 [IPControllerApp] Hub using DB backend: 'NoDB'
2016-03-06 03:28:12.749 [IPControllerApp] hub::created hub
2016-03-06 03:28:12.751 [IPControllerApp] writing connection info to /home/gms/.config/ipython/profile_mpi/security/ipcontroller-client.json
2016-03-06 03:28:12.754 [IPControllerApp] writing connection info to /home/gms/.config/ipython/profile_mpi/security/ipcontroller-engine.json
2016-03-06 03:28:12.758 [IPControllerApp] task::using Python leastload Task scheduler
2016-03-06 03:28:12.760 [IPControllerApp] Heartmonitor started
2016-03-06 03:28:12.808 [IPControllerApp] Creating pid file: /home/gms/.config/ipython/profile_mpi/pid/ipcontroller.pid
2016-03-06 03:28:14.792 [IPControllerApp] client::client 'a8441250-d3d7-4a0b-8210-dae327665450' requested 'registration_request'
2016-03-06 03:28:14.800 [IPControllerApp] client::client '12fd0bcc-24e9-4ad0-8154-fcf1c7a0e295' requested 'registration_request'
2016-03-06 03:28:18.764 [IPControllerApp] registration::finished registering engine 1:'12fd0bcc-24e9-4ad0-8154-fcf1c7a0e295'
2016-03-06 03:28:18.768 [IPControllerApp] engine::Engine Connected: 1
2016-03-06 03:28:20.800 [IPControllerApp] registration::purging stalled registration: 0
```

Shouldn't each of the 6 engines be registered?

2 of the engine's logs look like they registered fine:

```
2016-03-06 03:28:13.746 [IPEngineApp] Initializing MPI:
2016-03-06 03:28:13.746 [IPEngineApp] from mpi4py import MPI as mpi
mpi.size = mpi.COMM_WORLD.Get_size()
mpi.rank = mpi.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()

2016-03-06 03:28:14.735 [IPEngineApp] Loading url_file     u'/home/gms/.config/ipython/profile_mpi/security/ipcontroller-engine.json'
2016-03-06 03:28:14.780 [IPEngineApp] Registering with controller at tcp://127.0.0.1:34540
2016-03-06 03:28:15.282 [IPEngineApp] Using existing profile dir:    
u'/home/gms/.config/ipython/profile_mpi'
2016-03-06 03:28:15.286 [IPEngineApp] Completed registration with id 1
```

while the other registered with `id 0`

But, the other 4 engines gave a time out error:

```
2016-03-06 03:28:14.676 [IPEngineApp] Initializing MPI:
2016-03-06 03:28:14.689 [IPEngineApp] from mpi4py import MPI as mpi
mpi.size = mpi.COMM_WORLD.Get_size()
mpi.rank = mpi.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()

2016-03-06 03:28:14.733 [IPEngineApp] Loading url_file u'/home/gms/.config/ipython/profile_mpi/security/ipcontroller-engine.json'
2016-03-06 03:28:14.805 [IPEngineApp] Registering with controller at tcp://127.0.0.1:34540
2016-03-06 03:28:16.807 [IPEngineApp] Registration timed out after 2.0 seconds
```

Hmmm... I think I may try a reinstall of ipython tomorrow.

**EDIT UPDATE 3**

Conflicting versions of ipython were installed (looks like through apt-get and pip). Uninstalling and reinstall using `pip install ipython[all]`...

**EDIT UPDATE 4**

I hope someone is finding this useful AND I hope someone can weigh in at some point to help clarify a few things.

Anywho, I installed a virtualenv to deal isolate my environment, and it looks like some degree of success, I think. I fired up 'ipcluster start -n 4 --profile=mpi' on each of my nodes, then ssh'ed back into my head node and ran a test script, which first calls `ipcluster`. The following output: [image: signs of parallelism] So, it is doing some parallel computing.

However, when I run my test script that queries all the nodes, I just get the head node:

[image: no parallelism here]

But, again, if I just run the straight up `mpiexec` command, everything is hunky dory.

To add to the confusion, if I look at the processes on the nodes, I see all sorts of behavior to indicate they are working together: [image: monitor of processes]

And nothing out of the ordinary in my logs. Why am I not getting nodes returned in my second test script (code included here:):

```
# test_mpi.py
import os
import socket
from mpi4py import MPI

MPI = MPI.COMM_WORLD

print("{host}[{pid}]: {rank}/{size}".format(
    host=socket.gethostname(),
    pid=os.getpid(),
    rank=MPI.rank,
    size=MPI.size,
))
```

Comment: The notebook does not automatically start any of the parallel computing machinery, and if you're not using ipcluster, the `ipcluster_config.py` config file is probably not doing anything.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out after further researching the issue... I need to install NFS on my hosts and get ipcluster working. Seems to be the the least painless route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why, but I recreated my ipcluster_config.py file and again added c.MPILauncher.mpi_args = ["-machinefile", "path_to_file/machinefile"] to it and this time it worked - for some bizarre reason. I could swear I had this in it before, but alas...